# How to delete Entities with swipe to delete iOS tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I've been really struggling on getting my budget app to work properly with coreData. So far the app is capable of saving data that the user inputs and tableview can successfully load the data and display it properly.

The problem is I can't figure out how to delete just one item when the user swipes to delete on the table. I think my whole coreData model is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it or to set it up properly!

Here's my code in my ViewController

```
 /***************************************
* numberOfRowsInSection:
*  This function gets a count of all the
* objects that are stored in the MoneyEntity
* table.
****************************************/
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

  return CoreDataManager.fetchObjects().count

}

/***************************************
* cellForRowAt indexPath:
*  This function populates all the cells
* with the data from the MoneyEntity
* objects.
****************************************/
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


  let cell = self.budgetTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! cellLog

  //alternates between colors
  if (indexPath.row % 2 ) != 0
  {
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
  }
  else
  {
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  }

  // load data into cell

  cell.moneyLabel.text = "$\(String(format:"%.2f", CoreDataManager.fetchObjects()[indexPath.row].money))"
  cell.dateLabel.text = "\(CoreDataManager.fetchObjects()[indexPath.row].date)"
  cell.noteImage.image = UIImage(named: "notes")

  return cell

}

/***************************************
* editingStyle:
*  This function lets the user "swipe to delete"
* in the tableView
****************************************/
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
  if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
  {

     // **** what do I do here?????

     //why wont this work?!
     let context = CoreDataManager.getContext()
     context.deleteObject(CoreDataManager.fetchObjects()[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
     context.save(nil)


   //print(CoreDataManager.fetchObjects()[indexPath.row])

   //         var index = Int(indexPath.row)
   //         CoreDataManager.deleteSing

     // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
     self.budgetTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)


    //         budgetTable.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Ok and here's my code for my CoreDataManager class

```
class CoreDataManager: NSObject
{
/***************************************
* getContext:
*  This function sets us up with the abillity
* to start using coredata functions
****************************************/
public class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext
{
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}

/***************************************
* storeObject:
*  This function saves the data to a 
* MoneyEntity object
****************************************/
class func storeObject(destination:String, money:Double, date:String, note:String)
{
  let context = getContext()

  let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MoneyEntity", in: context)

  let managedObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

  //save data
  managedObj.setValue(money, forKey: "money")
  managedObj.setValue(date, forKey: "date")
  managedObj.setValue(note, forKey: "note")

  do
  {
     try context.save()
     print("Data save successful")
  }
  catch
  {
     print("Failed to save data")
     print(error.localizedDescription)

  }
 }

 /***************************************
* fetchObjects:
*  This function loads all the MoneyEntity
* objects into an array that gets returned
* to numberOfRowsInSection so that it can
* see how many MoneyEntity objects there are
* so that it can create the right about of
* cells.
****************************************/
class func fetchObjects() -> [moneyLog]
{
  var tempArray = [moneyLog]()

  let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<MoneyEntity> = MoneyEntity.fetchRequest()

  do {
     let fetchResult = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

     for item in fetchResult
     {
        let newMoneyLog = moneyLog(money: item.money, date: item.date!, note: item.note!)
        tempArray.append(newMoneyLog)
     }

  }
  catch {
     print("fetch faild")
  }

  return tempArray
}


/***************************************
* cleanCoreData:
*  This function clears all data from
* coreData.
****************************************/
class func cleanCoreData()
{
  let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<MoneyEntity> = MoneyEntity.fetchRequest()

  let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

  do {
     print("deleting all content")
     try getContext().execute(deleteRequest)
  } catch {
     print("There was a problem deleting all items")
  }

}
```

MoneyEntity data model

[image]

Comment: Rather than repeatedly calling `fetchObjects` younshould call it once and store the array it returns in a property. There is no need to keep going back to the persistent store. Does your delete functionget called?

Comment: The fetchObjects method converts the fetched NSManagedObjects to a different class, moneyLog.  So the deleteObject call is being passed a moneyLog object, cast as NSManagedObject, which won't work if moneyLog is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.  You need to rework your code so fetchObjects returns NSManagedObjects, or - better - a subclass.  And as @Paulw11 says, call it only once and store the result in an array.  Alternatively, consider using a NSFetchedResultsController as the datasource.

Comment: I missed that. Don't convert your managed object to another type. Just use a NSManagedObject subclass

Comment: Ok so my question is should I just ditch my moneyLog class completely then? I don't understand how to return a NSManagedObject. When I load it in to an Array back in the view controller, how does it get deleted from the database when I swipe to delete? I new to swift

Comment: Ok I think I just got it figured out! thanks